# Keycloak Docker container does not connect to MySQL database

Tags: mysql, docker, keycloak

I am trying to set up a Keycloak server inside a Docker container, and I wish
it to utilize a MySQL database stored on the host machine, but I want this
database to be managed by a MySQL instance that is also running inside a
Docker container. I cannot get this to work, however.

Thus far I have tried the following:

```
# Create network for keycloak
docker network create edci-network

# First start up MySQL server…
docker run \
    --name edci-keycloak-mysql \
    -d \
    --net edci-network \
    -e MYSQL_DATABASE=edci-keycloak \
    -e MYSQL_USER=edci-keycloak \
    -e MYSQL_PASSWORD=password \
    -v /path/to/local/database:/var/lib/mysql \
    -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root_password \
    mysql

# … then run Keycloak with token exchange enabled.
docker run \
    --name edci-keycloak \
    -d \
    -p 9000:8080 \
    --net edci-network \
    -e KEYCLOAK_USER=admin \
    -e KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD=admin \
    -e DB_ADDR=edci-keycloak-mysql \
    -e DB_PASSWORD=password \
    -e JAVA_OPTS_APPEND="
        -Dkeycloak.profile.feature.token_exchange=enabled
        -Dkeycloak.profile.feature.admin_fine_grained_authz=enabled
    " \
    quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:15.0.2
```

However, the Keycloak logs proclaim

> Using H2 database

as the server starts up. What am I doing wrong here? The MySQL Example
on the [Keycloak Docker Hub](https://hub.docker.com/r/jboss/keycloak/) page does not work as is either.

Note that *using Docker Compose is not an option*, so answers relying on it
are not considered. Thanks for any assistance.

---

Keycloak container logs: https://pastebin.com/b56cmxBJ.

Comment: Your docker run for keycloak; is there a `-e DB_USER=edci-keycloak`?

Comment: @gohm'c I tried it with that environment variable set as well, but it did not help.

Comment: You need that DB_USER and can you set `DB_ADDR=<your host primary IP>` and see if it works?

Comment: By "host primary IP" do you mean something like `kubernetes.docker.internal`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using predefined values (e.g. Keycloak container expect DB name `keycloak`), so you need to configure all DB details (env variables `DB_*`) explicitly:

```
# Create network for keycloak
docker network create edci-network

# First start up MySQL server…
docker run \
    --name edci-keycloak-mysql \
    -d \
    --net edci-network \
    -e MYSQL_DATABASE=edci-keycloak \
    -e MYSQL_USER=edci-keycloak \
    -e MYSQL_PASSWORD=password \
    -v /path/to/local/database:/var/lib/mysql \
    -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root_password \
    mysql

# … then run Keycloak with token exchange enabled.
docker run \
    --name edci-keycloak \
    -d \
    -p 9000:8080 \
    --net edci-network \
    -e KEYCLOAK_USER=admin \
    -e KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD=admin \
    -e DB_VENDOR=mysql \
    -e DB_ADDR=edci-keycloak-mysql \
    -e DB_DATABASE=edci-keycloak \
    -e DB_USER=edci-keycloak \
    -e DB_PASSWORD=password \
    -e JAVA_OPTS_APPEND="
        -Dkeycloak.profile.feature.token_exchange=enabled
        -Dkeycloak.profile.feature.admin_fine_grained_authz=enabled
    " \
    quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:15.0.2
```

Comment: Hmm. Strangely the Keycloak server is still refusing to start up, although the "Using H2 database" has been replaced with "Using MySQL database". Here are the latest logs: https://pastebin.com/yrYEMezD. The main cause seems to be on line 234: "Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'edci-keycloak'@'172.18.0.3' (using password: YES)"

Comment: I wonder if this is the cause (from MySQL Docker Hub page): "If you start your mysql container instance with a data directory that already contains a database (specifically, a mysql subdirectory), the $MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD variable should be omitted from the run command line; it will in any case be ignored, and the pre-existing database will not be changed in any way.".

Comment: Yup, I think that was the issue. The database might also have been created with the name "keycloak" at first, which caused a conflict.

Comment: Thanks a lot, in my case I forgot to specify -e DB_VENDOR=mysql.